# Cant quite seem to nail this regular expression whats up with it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

Im trying to strip out keyvalue pairs from a string. For example using:

```
key=cat key2=dog
```

I use the expression:

```
([^=])([\w-\s]*)\s
```

Which gives me:

cat
dog

However in reality the string to search is likely to contain other non alphabet characters like this:

```
192.168.20.31 Url=/flash/56553550_hi.mp4 Log=SESSIONSTART 
[16/Dec/2010:13:44:17 +0000] flash/56553550_hi.mp4 0 192.168.20.31 1 
[16/Dec/2010:13:44:17 +0000] 0 0 0 [0 No Error] 
[0 No Error [rtmp://helix.pete.videolibraryserver.com/flash/56553550_hi.mp4]
```

And I need to be able to pluck out the URL from it. However im not sure how I inject a catch all for all the character types into my original regexp. could someone show me?

Comment: Myabe this is one of those tasks better solved without regular expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out. Works like a beauty for me:

```
((?<=key[0-9]?=)[^\s]*(\s|$))+
```

`(?<=regex)` is a zero-width (non-consuming) look-behind. This ensures that the value is preceded by `key[0-9]?=`. You can adjust the `[0-9]` to suit your exact needs, but the `?` make that digit optional anyways. The value part is matching anything that is **not** a space: `[^\s]`. It keeps consuming, `*`, and terminates the value when it finds a space or end-of-string `(\s|$)`.

---

### Update

I started looking at the blob of data you gave as what you're actually searching over and modified the expression thus:

```
([^\s]+)=(.+?(?=([^\s]+=|$)))
```

Works great on the header data you provided (if you're copy/pasting into a tester, remember to remove the hard returns).

Matches:

`Url`,`/flash/56553550_hi.mp4`

`Log`,`SESSIONSTART [16/Dec/2010:13:44:17 +0000] flash/56553550_hi.mp4 0 192.168.20.31 1 [16/Dec/2010:13:44:17 +0000] 0 0 0 [0 No Error] [0 No Error [rtmp://helix.pete.videolibraryserver.com/flash/56553550_hi.mp4]`

***To not match the key** (only the value):*

```
[^\s]+=(.+?(?=([^\s]+=|$)))
```

---

**[RegEx Reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)**

[**RegEx Tester**](http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx)

Comment: thanks :-) I did some of my own researh into positive lookahead and lookbehind to strip our the value I wanted without including some parts of the actual match...Definitely have learned something.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, to capture non-space characters following `Url=`:

```
\bUrl=(\S*)
```

Or, if you want something more general to match all key/value pairs, try this:

```
\b(\S*)=(\S*)
```

Comment: thats great, just out of interest how would I get it to ignore the key and the = symbol and give the value? Using^?

Comment: your match stops after `SESSIONSTART` (when it reaches it's first space) neglecting the remainder of the "value" (which I'm assuming continues until another `key` is found).

Comment: @Pete2k I'm not sure what you mean, but to not capture the key, just get rid of the first set of enclosing parenthesis (this applies to Brad's answer as well).

Comment: @Brad You're right. I didn't realize that all of that data was actually part of the value for `Log`.  I'll leave my answer up in case someone is looking for a simpler RegEx for values that cannot contain spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your Url value allows only: alphanumeric, '.', and '_'; this regex should extract the value of the url.

Url=(?(\w|/|.)*)

The code to extract the value is:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"Url=(?(\w|/|\.)*)");
MatchCollection matchCollection = regex.Matches(inputString);

foreach(Match match in matchCollection)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["url"].Value);
}
```